# Литература по созданию сложных систем на PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, книги, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу на тему создания сложных систем php, mysql. Меня интересует не пособие по php или mysql, а примеры решения архитектуры в построении сложных web приложений. В первую очередь меня интересует, как правильно построить архитектуру базы данных.

Comment: Может быть, будет интересно посмотреть на уже существующие достаточно сложные БД. Например, [Wordpress](http://joemaller.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/wordpress_23_mysql_tables.pdf).

Comment: Очень рекомендую видеоуроки Евгения Попова evgeniypopov.com, особенно про PHP + MySQL. Всё предельно понятно и ясно. С хорошими примерами. А полученные знания можно закрепить любой толстой книгой по PHP. Он не такой сложный, как кажется.

Comment: Вы просто напросто обязаны изучить PHP, а архитектуру уже придумать, усовершенствовать, иначе зачем вам программирование?

Comment: Я на достаточно хорошем уровне владею PHP(ООП, шаблоны проектирования и прочее), и sql я владею на среднем уровне. Просто я не достаточно имею опыта в построении правильной архитектуры сложных баз данных. Только это меня интересует

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Comment: погугли Дмитрий Валак  Экстремальное создание сайтов на PHP и MySQL

Answer (score 3):

Если вас интересует, как правильно спроектировать базу в mysql, первым делом вам надо понять, как рабтает mysql. Для этого обязательно надо прочитать [High Perfomance MySQL](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6573935/) + любую книжку, где написано, что такое транзакции, внешние ключи, нормализация и т.п.

"Проектирование сложных систем" мало чем отличается от проектирования несложных систем. Всё те же стандартные решения и компромисы между ними. Стандартые решения, к сожалению, разбросаны в десятках статей и книг, но, я думаю, начать можно, например, с [Фаулера](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4884925/).

Comment: Вот единственный человек, который меня понял

Answer (score 1):

Энди Гутманс "Профессиональное программирование на PHP", посмотрите на досуге.

Answer (score 1):

Не советую брать курсы Попова, он не программист, и подходу него не правильный, новичкам - да, они не понимают многого :)